# tensorflow multi slice not reshape

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have 3D (64,64,64) shape (chair) when I reshape it using tf operation to (8,32,32,32) then do my operation Deep learning operation and then return it back using tf reshape to (64,64,64)  the shape looks very bad, actually there is no shape only strange looks unknown shape (100% not looks like chair)

but if I use function that I build to slice 32 by 32 and I stack them as (8,32,32,32) I use it as input to my DL Model. the output (8,32,32,32)  I use also combine function which I build to recombine by reversing the slice function I got good looking shape

the issue both function slice and combine numpy not tf. I have to train model end-to-end so I need equivalent function that slice or combine in tensorflow please

```
 def slice(self,size, obj):
    #print('inside')
    oldi = 0
    newi = 0
    oldj = 0
    newj = 0
    oldk = 0
    newk = 0
    lst = []
    s = obj.shape[0]
    s += 1
    for i in range(size, s, size):
        if (newi == s - 1):
            oldi = 0
        else:
            oldi = newi
        for j in range(size, s, size):
            if (newj == s - 1):
                oldj = 0
            else:
                oldj = newj
            for k in range(size, s, size):
                newi = i
                newj = j
                newk = k
                slc = obj[oldi:newi, oldj:newj, oldk:newk]

                #print(oldi,':',newi,',',oldj,':',newj,',',oldk,':',newk)
                #print(slc.shape)
                lst.append(slc)

                if (newk == s - 1):
                    oldk = 0
                else:
                    oldk = newk
                # print(slc.shape)
    return lst



def combine(self,lst, shape, size):
    oldi = 0
    newi = 0
    oldj = 0
    newj = 0
    oldk = 0
    newk = 0

    obj = np.zeros((shape, shape, shape))
    s = shape
    s += 1
    counter = 0
    for i in range(size, s, size):
        if (newi == s - 1):
            oldi = 0
        else:
            oldi = newi
        for j in range(size, s, size):
            if (newj == s - 1):
                oldj = 0
            else:
                oldj = newj
            for k in range(size, s, size):
                newi = i
                newj = j
                newk = k
                obj[oldi:newi, oldj:newj, oldk:newk] = lst[counter]
                counter += 1

                #print(oldi,':',newi,',',oldj,':',newj,',',oldk,':',newk)
                # print(slc.shape)

                if (newk == s - 1):
                    oldk = 0
                else:
                    oldk = newk

    return obj
```

Comment: Add the tensorflow code snippet that gave you the 'bad looking' shape.

Comment: just regular reshape operation if x=(64,64,64) I will do tf.reshape(x, (8,32,32,32))

Comment: what i want simply tf function that i slice (64,64,64) to (8,32,32,32) in one step and the reverse  in also one step

Answer (score 0):

in other words  I want tensorflow operation mimic

the following function

```
def combine(self,lst, shape, size):
oldi = 0
newi = 0
oldj = 0
newj = 0
oldk = 0
newk = 0

obj = np.zeros((shape, shape, shape))
s = shape
s += 1
counter = 0
for i in range(size, s, size):
    if (newi == s - 1):
        oldi = 0
    else:
        oldi = newi
    for j in range(size, s, size):
        if (newj == s - 1):
            oldj = 0
        else:
            oldj = newj
        for k in range(size, s, size):
            newi = i
            newj = j
            newk = k
            obj[oldi:newi, oldj:newj, oldk:newk] = lst[counter]
            counter += 1

            #print(oldi,':',newi,',',oldj,':',newj,',',oldk,':',newk)
            # print(slc.shape)

            if (newk == s - 1):
                oldk = 0
            else:
                oldk = newk

return obj
```